# Beefy + watchify requires multiple page refreshes to see changes

Tags: javascript, frontend, browserify

I'm using beefy as a dev server, and when I save a file, the page reloads, but I don't see the changes. I have to refresh 1 or 2 more times before the changes appear. Has anyone had this problem? This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "main": "app/js/index.js",
  "browser": {
    "jQuery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "visual-search": "./app/js/vendor/visualsearch.js"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "brfs",
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "visual-search": {
      "exports": "VS",
      "depends": [
        "jQuery:jQuery",
        "./node_modules/backbone/backbone.js:Backbone",
        "./node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:_"
      ]
    }
  },
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "backbone": "^1.1.2",
    "backbone-pouch": "^1.1.1",
    "chai": "^1.9.1",
    "jquery": "^2.1.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.10.5",
    "pouchdb": "^3.1.0",
    "underscore": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "beefy": "^2.1.1",
    "bluebird": "^2.5.3",
    "brfs": "^1.2.0",
    "browserify": "^6.3.3",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.8.1",
    "chai": "^1.9.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "^4.1.1",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "sinon": "^1.12.1",
    "sinon-as-promised": "^2.0.3",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.6.0",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.3.6",
    "useref-file": "^0.2.1",
    "watchify": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run pouch & npm run beefy",
    "pouch": "pouchdb-server --port 5984 --dir db",
    "beefy": "beefy app/js/App.js:js/bundle.js --cwd app --live --open",
    "build-vendor": "uglifyjs -mc app/js/vendor/*.js > build/_attachments/js/vendor.js",
    "browserify": "browserify app/js/App.js > build/_attachments/js/app.js",
    "uglify": "uglifyjs -mc build/_attachments/js/app.js",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run browserify",
    "clean": "rm -rf build/_attachments/js",
    "test": "testem ci"
  }
}
```

Comment: Found [this issue](https://github.com/chrisdickinson/beefy/issues/49) and [this pull request](https://github.com/chrisdickinson/beefy/pull/77)